# Build URL string from dictionary in ansible with filters

Tags: string, ansible, jinja2

In Ansible, I am trying to build a URL string starting from a dictionary.

This is the source dict:

```
query_string:
   UserName: myname
   Notes: abcd
   GenericField1: foo
```

This is what I would like to obtain:

```
UserName=myname&Notes=abcd&GenericField1=foo
```

I tried several combinations of jinja filers (urlencode, flatten, etc) but I cannot reach my goal.
Anyone has a suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

This solution is working properly:

```
  - name: Create query string from input params
    set_fact:
      URL_params: "{{ URL_params }}{{ (index > 0)|ternary('&','') }}{{ item.key }}={{ item.value | urlencode }}"
    loop: "{{  query_string | dict2items }}"
    loop_control:
      index_var: index
```

Comment: found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52144603/creating-a-comma-separated-string-from-a-dictionary-in-ansible

Answer (score 0):

Is this the code that you're looking for?

```
- set_fact:
    my_url: >
      UserName={{ query_string.UserName -}}
      &Notes={{ query_string.Notes -}}
      &GenericField1={{ query_string.GenericField1 -}}
```

Comment: I didn't specified that query_string isn't fixed, values can differ from time to time. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

If the `query_string` dictionary has more properties, this code provides you with the flexibility to use more field as needed

```
- name: build the url
  set_fact:
    myurl: "{{ myurl | default('') + item.key + '=' + item.value + '&' | regex_replace('\\&$', '') }}"
  loop: "{{ query_string|dict2items }}"
```

Comment: For some reasons this seems broken ... I'm double checking it.Thanks anyway :)

Comment: I forgot to mention that `dict2items` is available from Ansible 2.6: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html?#dict-filter

Answer (score 0):

Almost same as @EBAH:

```
- set_fact:
    url_str: "{{ (url_str | default('')) + ('&' if (index > 0) else '') + (item.key+'='+item.value| urlencode) }}"
  loop: "{{ query_string | dict2items }}"
  loop_control:
    index_var: index
```